# Glueing together relational data rows

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I have a sparse table structured like:

```
id | name      | phone          | account
```

There is no primary key or index

There are also null values. What I want is to "glue" data from different rows together, e.g.: 
Given

```
id | name      | phone          | account   
  1     null     '339-33-27'       4       
  null   'John'  '339-33-27'       4
```

I want to end up with

```
id | name       | phone           | account |
  1     'John'    '339-33-27'        4
```

However, I don't know which values are missed in the table. 
What are the general way to approach this kind of problem? Do I need to use only joins or might be recursive functions?

Update: Provided more clear example

```
id to account is many-to-many 
account to name is many-to-many 
phone to name is one-to-one
```

The database is basically raw transactional data 
What I want to is to get all the rows for which I already have / could find an account

Comment: Please don't each and every database you can find. Tag only the one you are using.

Comment: What if two rows have different non null values in the same column? Can this happen? If so, you should tell us what you expect to see... if not, I wonder what this table's may be ;)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: I don't think one could answer this question without knowing *why* you want to do this.  There are lots of operations which can group rows together (i.e., read up on the `GROUP BY` clause for your database), but how you use it depends very much upon what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Updated tags, @Frazz more clear explanation

Comment: @AndrewMiner In new terms  I want to have an account value set for as many rows as possible.

Comment: You still have not told us what you expect to obtain if the same column contains two different values :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then this might work. What you need is a self join

```
select t2.id, t1.name, t1.phone, t1.account
from table1 t1
join table1 t2 on t1.account = t2.account and t1.phone = t2.phone
where t1.name is not null
```

However this particular query relies on an assumption from your example data. My assumption is that if name is not null, Id will be null and the Id can be found by looking at the phone number and account. If this assumption is not true , then we may need more sample data to solve your problem.

Depending on the data, you might need left joins or to swap so that T1 gets the id and not the name and the where condition is that ID is not null. It's hard to tell with such a small data sample size.